# Modal a message dialog from other running thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, modal-dialog

I called a function existed in DLL, in start of my program in c++.
after that call returned, anyway in program i created main dialog inherited from CDialog by calling DoModal().
In the function in DLL, i ran another thread that its work is checking errors existence every 20 seconds for example. if an error exist, it will show error in a message dialog by ::MessageBoxW(...).

#### My problem:

When i show message dialog, user can interact with windows created by main thread (main dialog or its child windows). I Dont want it. The message dialog must be Modal on all threads so that user can not interact with program until close the message dialog.

#### Solution Options:

I think i have this options to select, before calling MessageBox in second thread:

1. Get all threads other than this thread that are running in my program and call sleep on their. But How?
2. Get all windows opened in my program in all threads and call EnableWindow(false) on their. But How? I found [EnumWindows(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx) but how do i Enumerate my own windows in the program?
3. Any suggestion?

#### Limitations:

These limitations must be satisfied in your suggested solution:

1. I dont want to modify source of main program (.exe). I am only allowed to change the DLL Source.
2. Passing handle of main dilaog to the DLL function, not allowed. because of above limitation and that creating main dialog is after calling the DLL function.

Comment: The UI should only be done in one thread. Your background thread should send a message to the main UI thread, telling it to display the according info. In other words, you will have to change both the DLL and the program using it.

Comment: Because you can't modify exe, you should explore GUI thread in the dll. That said I haven't really used GUI threads myself but something to consider on this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

It is already written in a comment: Only do such UI from one thread. So the answer  I am writing here is just second choice!

If the main thread is running you can get the handle of the current active window of this thread.
Pass it as a parent to your dialog and call DoModal.

But this will create a bunch of messages between the threads. If the main thread is waiting and does not process any messages your program may hang.

Tipp: Don't pass a pointer to a CWnd from the mainthread. Get the window handle and use the CWnd::FromHandle to get a pointer to the window object. Pass this to the constructor of the CDialog object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you said `Get the handle of the current active window of main thread`. But How can i do it in the other thread?